# Dynamically create components that takes in setState

Tags: reactjs

I have to use a Select component that takes in a `value` argument and a `setValue` argument. Where I need to pass in a state and a set state.

eg:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState();
...
return (
    ...
    <Select value={value} setValue={setValue} options={optionsArray}/>
)
```

Now I need to dynamically create multiple of these `Select` components based on an user input. How do I declare my `state` and `setState` variables for this task?

I was thinking of using `state` as an object array, eg. `value['option1']` but I can't figure out how I can pass in the `setValue` part, so far I have tried passing in a custom function such as:

```
const setOptionValue = (value) = {
    value.push({option1: value})
}
```

However I am stuck because `setOptionValue` method does not know what the corresponding `option` is (doesn't know which one of the select field the user changed)

Any tips on how to solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your way is a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and maybe a [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) is better way in this case.

Edit the Select component or wrap the Select component into a new one.

```
const SelectMe = ({id, defaultValue, onValueChanged, options}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
    useEffect(()=>{
        onValueChanged({id, value})
    }, [value])
    return <Select value={value} setValue={setValue} options={optionsArray}/>
}
```

Here we got `id`, the key to identify user's input, and you can get the selected value when user do a select action.